# Identifying nonempty tables in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to find data in a database with hundreds of tables. I am just going through and writing simple `select *` queries for all of the tables checking them one by one. It is taking forever! I was wondering if there is a way to write a query to filter all of the tables with at least 1 row in the database. Is this possible?

Comment: What are you going to do with your list of tables which have at least one row? What's the real end goal here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with 
function f(tabname in varchar2) return int as
  res int;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) cnt from "'||tabname||'" where rownum=1' into res;
  return res;
end;
select table_name, f(table_name) chk
from user_tables;
```

Results:

```
TABLE_NAME                            CHK
------------------------------ ----------
STRVALS                                 1
MY_EMP                                  1
TBL_3                                   1
TBL_1                                   1
TLOCK                                   1
DATES                                   1
B                                       1
A                                       1
C                                       1
T0                                      0
```

Or `select count(*) from dual where exists(...)`:

```sql
with 
function f(tabname in varchar2) return int as
  res int;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) cnt from dual where exists(select 1 from "'||tabname||'")' into res;
  return res;
end;
select table_name, f(table_name) chk
from user_tables
```

Answer (score 5):

If your database is being properly maintained, you'll have optimizer statistics.

If you tables are missing stats, you can collect them thusly:

```
BEGIN
        dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(
                                      ownname => 'HR'
                                    , estimate_percent => X -- note the higher you go here, the more work will be done
        );
    END;
```

Then, QUERY THE STATISTICS, not your tables.

```
SELECT num_rows
     , table_name
  FROM sys.dba_all_tables
 WHERE owner      = 'HR'
```

You can then QUICKLY see what tables are empty or not - based on how accurate your stats are.

If you use dynamic SQL to run a SELECT COUNT(*) on every table in your schema, and your schema and/or tables are HUGE, you are going to have a very bad experience, and perhaps cause performance issues for your database.

[image]

Comment: If just counting the rows in all tables is going to upset the DBA, gathering statistics on them (which will read them multiple times, sort plenty and probably cause execution plans to change) is surely going to annoy them when all you want to know is if they have at least one row.

Comment: if you don't have stats, the optimizer is going to have horrible plans to begin with, one

Comment: @AndrewSayer I've amended my answer with more nuance as you've correctly pointed out